# multiple authors with some common affiliations

Tags: titles, templates, ieeetran

I am tryingto get something like the following using `\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran}` but finding it difficult to add distinct emails to each author.

[image]

This is what I have now

```
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Author  One \IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
Author  Two \IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
Author  Three \IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, 
Author  Four \IEEEauthorrefmark{1} and
Author  Five \IEEEauthorrefmark{3}}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}Affiliation One, Country}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Affiliation Two, Country}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}Affiliation Three, Country}}
```

My output is [image]

**My question is how can we add emails of the authors below their names?** (I can use an additional line below the affiliations but I am interested in making it as in the first figure)

Comment: This depends a lot on the style of the organisation, in this case, IEEE (or is it IEEE CS?). If you search for the style, you'd also find some style manual.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using it bu not any success yet! Is there any other ways to get what I want by including some other packages?